# CAKeyframeAnimation keyTimes set up

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

This is my code:

```
- (void)animateImages
{
    self.emoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 160, 50, 50)];
    self.emoImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:emoImageView];

    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_1.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_2.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_3.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_4.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_5.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_6.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_7.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_8.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_9.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_10.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_11.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_12.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_13.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_14.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_15.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_16.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_17.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_18.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_19.png"].CGImage,
                       (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley64_1_20.png"].CGImage, nil];


    NSMutableArray *keyTimes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.04f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.08f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.12f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.16f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.20f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.24f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.28f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.32f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.36f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.40f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.44f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.48f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.52f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.56f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.60f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.64f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.68f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.72f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.76f], nil];


    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
    [anim setKeyTimes:keyTimes];
    [anim setValues:values];
    [anim setKeyPath:@"contents"];
    //[anim setCalculationMode:@"discrete"];
    [anim setRepeatCount: 90000];
    [self.emoImageView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
}
```

The animation will happen in a fixed `UIImageView`. The time interval between frames is 0.04. If I run this, the animation playing with a fast speed. But If I set the duration like this `[anim setDuration:0.76];`, It plays perfectly. What's the thing I did wrong here?

Comment: Holy mother of mercy. Did you consider using image view to play your pngs or FLAnimatedImage to play a gif?

Comment: @Andy I am afraid, yes, I did. Why? :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already explained this in an answer to your other question on the same subject.

The times in key times are fractions of the total interval of the animation, not fractions of a second.

In the code you posted you don't specify any duration at all. The default duration for an animation must be something short like .2 seconds, so when you don't provide a duration, you get a very short duration. If you specify a longer duration, it runs slower.

Say the default duration is .2 seconds. Your keyTimes values vary by .04, and 
.2 * .04 = .008 seconds, or 8 thousandths of a second. If I'm right and the default duration of an animation is .2 seconds, you are giving each frame .008 seconds. Anything shorter than .01666 seconds/frame (1/60th of a second) is pointless, as the animation will have to skip frames.

In fact, since the docs don't specify a default duration, the results when you don't specify a duration are probably undefined.

Comment: That means my keyTimes array will be a collection of percentage, which will combined according to my time interval. And then also I have to set the duration as well. My total duration is 0.76. Here is first 3 and last array of my keyTimes array. Please tell me is it the correct one.
keyTims [0] = 0.0, 
keyTims [1] = (0+0.04)/.76), keyTims [2] = (0+0.04)+ 0.04) /.76).....keyTims [19] = 1.0,
Right?

Comment: The keyTimes are not the duration of each event, they are the starting time, from 0 to 1.0, for each stage in the animation. The difference between a key time and the previous key time determines its relative duration. See my post in your other thread on this subject, where I posted code that would generate any number of evenly spaced key times. I really did fully answer your question in that other thread.

Comment: You don't divide the keyTimes entries by .76. The system MULTIPLIES the duration by the values of each keyTimes entry to decide when to start that step in the animation.